# How to save data between levels in UE4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am making a death system for my game. The player gets 3 lives, and once all 3 lives run out, a death screen is opened. I ran into a problem. I need to save the lives left so I can access it between levels. I have never had to save any data before, so I am not sure how to do this. Here is a picture of my death system blueprint.

[Blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTrPO.png)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to save data between levels.

#### 1. GameInstance

GameInstance is an object, that lives from start to an end of game process. It does not get removed on level switch. So, in order to pass some data, you can create your own GameInstance class, create the properties you need to pass between levels, and set your GameInstance class in Project Settings > Maps & Modes > Game Instance.

Before you switch level, just set variable in your game instance, and after switch, read it.

https://ibb.co/DR5zS5M

https://ibb.co/FYbyzfB

https://ibb.co/vx7s2SX

#### 2. Using save system

With save system you simply save your progress and load it after switch. The idea here is to save all the data by using SaveGameToSlot before the level switch, and after it, load the data with LoadGameFromSlot.

This is not an elegant solution though. It works very well if you load save only on game start and properly combine it with GameInstance, using a save game object as a progress container, so you can save progress, and pass it over different levels using one object.

https://ibb.co/qndzbp6

*SaveGame blueprint can be created the same way as a GameInstance blueprint. See screenshots*